# File not getting downloaded from ftp

Tags: java, file, ftp

Code:

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

```
public class FtpDownloader {

    // Server Credentials
    String host = "ip";
    String username = "user";
    String password = "pass";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new FtpDownloader().downloadFile();
    }

    public void downloadFile() {
        try {
            FTPClient client_ftp = new FTPClient();
            FileOutputStream fos = null;

            client_ftp.connect(host);
            client_ftp.login(username, password);

            System.out.println("Connected : " + client_ftp.isConnected());

            fos = new FileOutputStream("d://update_mac.txt");

            Boolean file_got = client_ftp.retrieveFile("/update/update_mac.txt", fos);

            System.out.println("Downloaded : " + file_got);

            fos.close();

            client_ftp.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see am trying to download a file from the ftp server but When i run the code the connection is established but the file doesn't get downloaded it shows 0kb on my system.What you think the reason may be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I Have also tried this http://www.javabeat.net/tips/36-file-upload-and-download-using-java.html method but then it gives me malformed url exception,but when i put the same url in my browser it gives me the file.

Comment: The `FTPClient` is not part of standard Java API, but this one is recognizeable as the one from Apache Commons Net. In the future questions, please mention 3rd party libraries explicitly.

Comment: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient; this is the api am using

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use one of these parameter-combinations for your connect() method call:

```
void    connect(InetAddress host)
void    connect(InetAddress host, int port)
void    connect(InetAddress host, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
void    connect(String hostname)
void    connect(String hostname, int port)
void    connect(String hostname, int port, InetAddress localAddr, int localPort)
```

You might have tried `connect("127.0.0.1")` which is not one of these combinations.